# Why my styles works only after editing them directly in browser (even if no true changes)?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I notice this problem in Google Chrome 27

The style:

```
.hide-submit-text
{
    background: url("/sites/default/files/images/throbber2.gif") no-repeat scroll right center transparent;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    width: 98px;
}
```

JS Code (from Hide Submit module to Drupal 7 - https://drupal.org/project/hide_submit)

```
  // Bind to form submit.
  $('form', context).submit(function (e) {
    if (! $form.hasClass('hideSubmitButton-processed')) {
        return;
    }
    var settings = Drupal.settings.hide_submit;
    var $inp;
    if (!e.isPropagationStopped()) {
      if (settings.hide_submit_method == 'disable') {
        $('input.form-submit', $form).attr('disabled', 'disabled').each(function (i) {
          var $button = $(this);
          if (settings.hide_submit_css) {
            $button.addClass(settings.hide_submit_css);
          }
          if (settings.hide_submit_abtext) {
            $button.val($button.val() + ' ' + settings.hide_submit_abtext);
          }
          $inp = $button;
        });

        if ($inp && settings.hide_submit_atext) {
          $inp.after('<span class="hide-submit-text">' + Drupal.checkPlain(settings.hide_submit_atext) + '</span>');
        }
      }
      else {
        var pdiv = '<div class="hide-submit-text' + (settings.hide_submit_hide_css ? ' ' + Drupal.checkPlain(settings.hide_submit_hide_css) + '"' : '') + '>' + Drupal.checkPlain(settings.hide_submit_hide_text) + '</div>';
        if (settings.hide_submit_hide_fx) {
          $('input.form-submit', $form).addClass(settings.hide_submit_css).fadeOut(100).eq(0).after(pdiv);
          $('input.form-submit', $form).next().fadeIn(100);
        }
        else {
          $('input.form-submit', $form).addClass(settings.hide_submit_css).hide().eq(0).after(pdiv);
        }
      }
      // Add a timeout to rerset the buttons (if needed).
      if (settings.hide_submit_reset_time) {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
          hideSubmitResetButtons(null, $form);
        }, settings.hide_submit_reset_time);
      }
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```

Background appears only after I changed any value chrome css editor, e.g height. When I come back to previous value, background still appears, but never works without live changes.

.hide-submit-text element is showed after JS event (click)

Background is animated gif.

Comment: You have tagged this with `google-chrome`, is the issue Chrome-specific?

Comment: Do I miss something? Google Chrome specific, but you speak about FireBug (FireFox)

Comment: Check the network log (ctrl+shift+i). Does the picture get loaded?

Comment: My mistake, I mean Chrome console

Comment: Are you able to share a link? Or create a jsfiddle? How many CSS files did you include?

Comment: I try to create fiddle, maybe this is because of animating gif?

Comment: Another thing is that element is shown after JS event (click)

Comment: Did you try with a different image - a non-animated GIF?

Comment: PNG works, only GIF is making trouble. I notice in NETWORK tab of Chrome console that gif file download status is cancelled